# Powershell filter results don't match results from a pipeline

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I can use the following commands produce the desired output without any blank lines.

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem $Home | Out-String | ForEach-Object {($_.tostring()).split([Environment]::Newline)} | Where-Object {$_}
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Contacts
d-r--        19/03/2020     10:48            Desktop
d-r--        19/03/2020     10:48            Documents
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Downloads
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Favorites
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Links
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Music
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Pictures
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Saved Games
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Searches
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Videos
PS C:\>
```

However if I create a filter to do the same job it doesn't work.

```
PS C:\> filter Strip-Blanks ()
>> {
>>   $input | Out-String | ForEach-Object {($_.tostring()).split([Environment]::Newline)} | Where-Object {$_}
>> }
>>
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem $Home | Strip-Blanks
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Contacts
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        19/03/2020     10:48            Desktop
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        19/03/2020     10:48            Documents
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Downloads
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Favorites
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Links
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Music
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Pictures
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Saved Games
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Searches
    Directory: C:\Users\user
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        03/04/2019     15:50            Videos
PS C:\>
```

Obviously when piping the results from `Get-ChildItem` to my filter each (file/folder) object is being passed separately and ends up being displayed with it's own header.  The question is why doesn't this happen when piping the output through `Out-String` in the first example and can I get my filter to behave in the same way?

Thank you.

Comment: the `Out-String` cmdlet normally adds a newline to every string it outputs. have you tried simply NOT using that? PoSh will normally try to group things for you ...

Comment: Simply do `Get-ChildItem $Home`. That's all. Don't try to force this array of FileInfo and DirectoryInfo **objects** into a string and somehow split that back again to look like a table.

Comment: If I leave out ```Out-String``` I just get a list of folder and file names without the attributes column headers etc.

Comment: What I was trying to achieve was a filter I can use just about everywhere to remove blank lines from an output stream.  I have more or less achieved what I wanted, but I still don't understand why it behaves differently from what is essentially the same thing in the first example - and that bugs me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky. In the first example, out-string is blocking until it has all the lines. Your filter would have to do the same.  Notice the delay until all 3 numbers are input.

```
& { 1;sleep 1;2;sleep 1;3 } | out-string
```

If you take out-string out of the filter, it would work.  Out-String outputs *one* multiline string.

```
filter Strip-Blanks {
  $input | 
  ForEach-Object {($_.tostring()).split([Environment]::Newline)} | 
  Where-Object {$_}
 }

Get-ChildItem | Out-String | Strip-Blanks

    Directory: /Users/js/foo
UnixMode   User             Group                 LastWriteTime           Size Name
--------   ----             -----                 -------------           ---- ----
-rw-r--r-- js               staff               3/19/2020 22:59              3 file1
-rw-r--r-- js               staff               3/19/2020 22:59              3 file2
-rw-r--r-- js               staff               3/19/2020 22:59              3 file3
```